# sum multiple values from inputs and selects in form

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to sum the values from multiple SELECTS and INPUTS, this is what i have so far:

**HTML**

```
<label>Item#1</label>
<select name="price[]" id="sel_1">
    <option value="">Options</option>
    <option value="4.00">Small</option>
    <option value="8.00">Medium</option>
</select>
<br>
<label>Item#2</label>
<select name="price[]">
    <option value="">Options</option>
    <option value="4.00">Small</option>
    <option value="8.00">Medium</option>
</select>
<br>
<label>Item#3</label>
<select name="price[]">
    <option value="">Options</option>
    <option value="4.00">Small</option>
    <option value="8.00">Medium</option>
</select>
<br>
<label>Item#4</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="1.00" id="price[3]" name="price[]">
<br>
<label>Item#5</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="2.00" id="price[3]" name="price[]">
<br>
<label>Item#6</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="3.00" id="price[3]" name="price[]">
<br> <span id="usertotal"> </span>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function () {
    var tot = 0;
    $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
        tot += Number($(this).val());
    });
    tot += Number($('#sel_1').val());
    $('#usertotal').html(tot)
});

$('#sel_1').change(function () {
    $('input:checkbox').trigger('change');
});
```

As you can notice it only sum the value from first select i need it too sum from all the selects.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/B9ufP/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:
(I simplified a bit your code)

```
(function ($) {
    var $total = $('#usertotal');
    $('input,select:selected').on('change', function () {
        var tot = 0;
        $(':checked, select').each(function () {
            tot += ~~this.value;
        });
        $total.html(tot)
    });
}(jQuery))
```

Demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/zFCvV/7/)**

Comment: You shouldn't use the `Number` constructor. Either use `parseInt(this.value,10)` or `~~this.value`. You also should cache `$('#usertotal')` outside of the `change` event hander so you aren't running that selector over and over. http://jsfiddle.net/zFCvV/2/ something like that.

Comment: @Zero21xxx, good point. I have to go sleep now, if you want please edit. Its a CW now. Thanks

Comment: thanks for ur fast answer... it's working ...quick question how can i make it get a attr instead of the value? `var per_op = $(this).attr("ref");
        tot += Number(per_op);`

Comment: @Sergio, `parseInt` would be wrong since I assume he could have non-zero decimals.

Comment: the UPDATED code is showing 8 instead of 4 when i select first option..something is wrong

Comment: @Ered, I fixed it now. There was a `:selected` missing inside the each loop. So it was counting double, both from the select value and the option value.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be fancy, you can also use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to sum up the values.

Note that if you have decimals, use `parseFloat`.

```
var total = [].reduce.call($('select, :checkbox:checked'), function (pv, cv) {
    return parseFloat(pv.value) + parseFloat(cv.value);
});
```